# What addon or setting provides this cooldown bar

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I've been watching some videos of folk doing trials and saw this cooldown / casting bar. Does anyone know what addon provides it please?

[image: Screenshot of a trial group in Elder Scrolls Online]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw a streamer using it and asked them.
This is the [Combat Metronome (GCD Tracker)](https://www.esoui.com/downloads/info2373-CombatMetronomeGCDTracker.html) addon by Darianopolis.